# Ini и RadioButton в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

В .ini при запуске и отметке (поочередно) всех RadioButton записываются все переменные со значением 1, как это исправить?

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) +  '.ini');
  if RadioButton1.Checked  then
     Ini.WriteBool('Main', 'view1', RadioButton1.Checked)
  else
     if RadioButton2.Checked then
        Ini.WriteBool('Main', 'view2', RadioButton2.Checked)
     else
        Ini.WriteBool('Main', 'view3', RadioButton3.Checked);

Ini.Free;
end;
```

Доп. вопрос: как сохранить .ini в любую папку?

Доп. вопрос 2: как на основе ini-файла (например view1=1, остальные 0)  написать "Вы выбрали 1й вариант!"

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте сразу несколько разных вопросов

Comment: Сохранить в любую папку - указанием пути к INI в любой папке (перед этим ее надо создать), очевидно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в неправильной постановке задачи, ведь нужно записать не 3 переменных, а одну => записал ее в колонку(?) View, используя в качестве определения название кнопок

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
   Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) +  '.ini');
   if Top.Checked  then
      Ini.WriteString('Выбор расположения окна', 'View', Top.Name)
   else
      if Centre.Checked then
         Ini.WriteString('Выбор расположения окна', 'View', Centre.Name)
      else
         Ini.WriteString('Выбор расположения окна', 'View', Bottom.Name);

   Ini.Free;
   end;
```

Доп. Вопросы остались:

1) как сохранить .ini в любую папку?;

2) вывод настроек из ini

```
 if view=top then (например) 
 ShowMessage('Верх');
```

Comment: Обычно после `Create` (`Ini := TIniFile.Create...`) ставят блок `try..finally`, а в секции `finally`, в вашем случае, `Ini.Free`, на случай, если что-то пойдет не так. P.S. Чтобы получить ответ на ваши дополнительные вопросы, создайте новые вопросы с описанием проблемы.